# Code not working inside a class

Tags: python, class

i'm trying to solve an exercice which consists in a primal factorization of a given number.

```
def primes(n):
    p=[]
    for a in range(2,n+1):
        if (is_prime(a)): p.append(a)
    return p

def is_prime(number):
    for n in range(2,number):
        if not number%n : return False
    return True

def factor(z):
    p=primes(z)
    fact={}
    if z in p:
        fact[z]=1
    else:
        for n in p:
            while z%n==0 and (z/n not in p):
                if n not in fact: fact[n]=1
                else: fact[n]+=1
                z/=n  
            if z%n==0 and (z/n in p):
                if n in fact: fact[n]+=1+(z/n==n)
                else:
                    fact[n]=1
                    fact[z/n]=1+(z/n==n)
                break


    return fact

print factor(13)
```

My code work like a charm; but the exercice wants me to put it in a class starting with :

```
class PrimeFactorizer:
    #your code here
```

Which would be call with `PrimeFactorizer(n).factor`

When i add the working code above into

```
class PrimeFactorizer:
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.z=z
```

It returns me an empty stuff when calling `PrimeFactorizer(13).factor`
Could someone give me a hint on what i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: `.factor` or `.factor()` ?

Comment: instructions says .factor

tbh i don't really know the difference :p

Comment: Read about `class` in python documentation

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
class PrimeFactorizer:
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.z=z

    def primes(self,n):
        p=[]
        for a in range(2,n+1):
            if (self.is_prime(a)): p.append(a)
        return p

    def is_prime(self,number):
        for n in range(2,number):
            if not number%n : return False
        return True

    def factor(self):
        p=self.primes(self.z)
        fact={}
        if self.z in p:
            fact[self.z]=1
        else:
            for n in p:
                while self.z%n==0 and (self.z/n not in p):
                    if n not in fact: fact[n]=1
                    else: fact[n]+=1
                    self.z/=n
                if self.z%n==0 and (self.z/n in p):
                    if n in fact: fact[n]+=1+(self.z/n==n)
                    else:
                        fact[n]=1
                        fact[self.z/n]=1+(z/n==n)
                    break
        return fact

print PrimeFactorizer(8).factor() # Output: {2: 3}
print PrimeFactorizer(13).factor() # Output: {13: 1}}
```

Comment: i can't pass the test as instructions says .factor and not .factor()

Trying to figure out the difference :p

Comment: Well you can add self.factor() to the end of __init__, and change the return fact into print fact. In that case you can call "PrimeFactorizer(13).factor" and it will print {13:1}. But i will print the same when "PrimeFactorizer(13)" is called.